# Trouble creating a folder in Box.com using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, box-api, boxapiv2

I am building a web app using the Box API, but I'm having trouble simply creating a folder in the root directory. The token is set to a developer token which should be active.

The error I'm receiving now is `Bad Request`. What is wrong with this code? I'm also having trouble receiving authentication for the user, but I decided to tackle this first.

```
function createTestFolder() {
    $.ajax('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders', 
    {
        data: { name: 'CreatedFolderFromjQuery', parent: { id: '0' } },
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + window.token);
        },
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            alert(status);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert(error); }
    });
}
```

**EDIT :**  When I change the URL to `https://box.com/api/1.0/folders`, I seem to get a successful response. That is, the `success` function gets called, rather than the `error` function. However, the folder is still not uploaded to my account.

**EDIT 2 :** Using the curl command line and following the API documentation, I still receive the same error message. Here are the details:

```
{"type":"error", "status":400, "code":"bad_request", "context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter", "name":"entity_body", "message":"Invalid value ''{name:New Folder,'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair"}]}, "help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors", "message":"Bad Request", "request_id":"128521198353f4fc831c7e6"}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: parent
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I have solved my own question. I am not familiar with jQuery, and here was my mistake:

```
data: { name: 'CreatedFolderFromjQuery', parent: { id: '0' } },
```

With jQuery's AJAX API, `data` needs to be a string. I needed to serialize my POST data into JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'CreatedFolderFromjQuery', parent: { id: '0' } }),
```

Once I realized this, and added the `JSON.stringify()` the request was sent properly.